# Why does the classical trolley problem have a 1 to 5 ratio

Tags: utilitarianism

I'm just starting to wet my feet with Philosophy but of course, I've known about the trolley problem for a long time.

However it just occurred to me that the classical version of this problem always has 1 person on one track and 5 people on the other one. Even on Wikipedia, the only "vanilla" trolley problem is a 1vs5.

Now, I'm going to probably ask the dumbest question you ever read, but: Why five? Why not simply a 1-to-2 ratio? The problem is still there, Utilitarianism would still dictate that sacrificing one to save two people is the better choice.

Comment: Tradition I guess. Also some people would say to let the 5 die, and they might find it easier to say that if it was only 2, so to have 5 makes them think more.

Comment: It is just to emphasize that utilitarian quantities push one in a particular direction.  Two people is marginal, 100 people makes a slam-dunk difference for most people, 5 vs 1 -- that is enough to clarify that quantity MAY matter in moral decisions, and deciding how much is something we need to figure out.

Comment: Yes but that's the point, the experiment should start with 2vs1 and then check if by increasing the ratio the answer changes. And if it does, ask why it changes. From a strictly rational POV there should be no difference at all between 2v1 and 100v1. 
Both situations are "A > B and therefore i save A".
I think the other variations, with loved ones, with elderly etc... are way less interesting than understanding why a bigger quantitative difference will make you more/less rational when answering the problem.